# bitcoin testnet is mining about 50 blocks per minute right now - why?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet

The bitcoin test network is mining about 50 blocks every minute for the last several hours. What is going on?

You can see here: https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why?

Because someone set his mining software to testnet. Sorry, this answer is useless, but there is no better answer for this question :) I doubt that the owner of hash power would show his reasons. I do not want to speculate about testing new mining hardware by developers.

Answer (score 6):

There is an adjustment for the testnet when a block takes 20 minutes or longer to mine, it will adjust the difficulty down to 1. This was caused presumably because of the difference between blocktimes of `1356765` and `1356766` because block `1356767` was reset to 1.

Every 2016 blocks, the difficulty is adjusted, but it can only be increased by a factor of 4 each time.

`pow.cpp` as of version 0.16.2

```
// Special difficulty rule for testnet:
// If the new block's timestamp is more than 2* 10 minutes
// then allow mining of a min-difficulty block.
if (pblock->GetBlockTime() > pindexLast->GetBlockTime() + params.nPowTargetSpacing*2)
    return nProofOfWorkLimit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin's difficulty adjusts only every 2016 blocks (though the calculation is done on the previous 2015 blocks, due to an off-by-one error), and there is a maximum limit to the degree of the adjustment. This means that when the hash rate spikes—as it does when someone points a whole rig to the testnet as @amaclin stated—it can take a while until the difficulty adjusts to the point where the block interval reaches 10 minutes again.